# Why does VkAccessFlagBits include both read bits and write bits?

Tags: memory, synchronization, vulkan

In vulkan.h, every instance of `VkAccessFlagBits` appears in a pair that contains a `srcAccessMask` and a `dstAccessMask`:

```
VkAccessFlags      srcAccessMask;
VkAccessFlags      dstAccessMask;
```

In every case, according to my understanding, the purpose of these masks is to help designate two sets of operations, such that results of operations in the first set will be visible to operations in the second set.  For instance, write operations occurring prior to a barrier should not get hung up in caches but should instead propagate all the way to locations from which they can be read after the barrier.  Or something like that.

The access flags come in both READ and WRITE forms:

```
/* ... */
VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT = 0x00000020,
VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT = 0x00000040,
VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT = 0x00000080,
VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT = 0x00000100,
/* ... */
```

But it seems to me that `srcAccessMask` should probably always be some sort of `VK_ACCESS_*_WRITE_BIT` combination, while `dstAccessMask` should always be a combination of `VK_ACCESS_*_READ_BIT` values.  If that is true, then the READ/WRITE distinction is identical to and implicit in the src/dst distinction, and so it should be good enough to just have VK_ACCESS_SHADER_BIT etc., without READ_ or WRITE_ variants.

Why are there READ_ and WRITE_ variants, then?  Is it ever useful to specify that some read operations must fully complete before some other operations have begun?  Note that all operations using `VkAccessFlagBits` produce (I think) execution dependencies as well as memory dependencies.  It seems to me that the execution dependencies should be good enough to prevent earlier reads from receiving values written by later writes.

Answer (score 3):

While writing this question I encountered a statement in the Vulkan specification that provides at least part of an answer:

> Memory dependencies are used to solve data hazards, e.g. to ensure that write operations are visible to subsequent read operations (read-after-write hazard), as well as write-after-write hazards. Write-after-read and read-after-read hazards only require execution dependencies to synchronize.

This is from the section **6.4. Execution And Memory Dependencies**.  Also, from earlier in that section:

> The application must use memory dependencies to make writes visible before subsequent reads can rely on them, and before subsequent writes can overwrite them. Failure to do so causes the result of the reads to be undefined, and the order of writes to be undefined.

From this I surmise that, yes, the execution dependencies produced by the Vulkan commands that involve these access flags probably do free you from ever having to put a `VK_ACCESS_*_READ_BIT` into a `srcAccessMask` field--but that you might in fact want to have READ_ flags, WRITE_ flags, or both in some of your `dstAccessMask` fields, because apparently it's possible to use an explicit dependency to prevent read-after-write hazards in such a way that write-after-write hazards are NOT prevented.  (And maybe vice-versa?)

Like, maybe your Vulkan will sometimes decide that a write does not actually need to be propagated all the way through a particular cache to its final specified destination for the sake of a subsequent read operation, IF Vulkan happens to know that that read operation will simply read from that same cache, saving some time?  But then a second write might happen, and write to a different cache, and there'll be two caches left in a race (with the choice of winner undefined) to send their two values to the same spot.  Or something?  Maybe my mental model of these caches is entirely wrong.

It is fairly solidly established, at least, that memory barriers are confusing.

Comment: Anyway if somebody who unlike me actually knows how these caches or whatever work on some real hardware wanted to explain how it could really be important for Vulkan to be told that one barrier was a write-read barrier while another was a write-write barrier--like why, in detail, does it not just handle both the same way? (or did I actually get that right??)--then I would be glad of that.  But an ordinary Vulkan user prolly doesn't really need to know that I suppose

Comment: I am quite sure it is not about HW itself. If anything it would be something subtle about how driver handles things.

Comment: Hardware thread scheduling could include sharding based on write address. The shard would share cache making it possible to avoid write-after-write without cache flush (it would only require execution order synchronization). I don't know if any hardware actually implements this type of sharding. But Vulkan specification aims to put complete control to application which requires very verbose description of operations to support all types of possible hardware equally optimally.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over all the possibilities:

- read–read — well yeah that one is pretty useless. Khronos seems to agree [#131](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/131) it is pointless value in `src` (basically equivalent to `0`).
- read–write — execution dependency should be sufficient to synchronize without this. Khronos seems to agree [#131](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/131) it is pointless value in `src` (basically equivalent to `0`).
- write–read — that's the obvious and most common one.
- write–write — similar reason to write–read above. Without it the order of the writes would be undefined. It is a bit pointless for most situations to write something you haven't even read in between. But hey, now you have a way to synchronize it.

You can provide bitmask of more of these masks to both src and dst. In which case it makes sense to have both masks for driver to sort the dependencies out for you. (I don't expect performance overhead from this on API level, so it is allowed as convenience)

From API design perspective, it could mean adding different enum for `srcAccess`. But perhaps `_READ` variants could just be forbidden in `srcAccess` through "Valid Usage", making this argument weak. The `src == READ` variant might have been kept, because it is benign.

Comment: This seems to conflict with my sketchy claim (in my answer) that the READ_BIT flags never need to be set in srcAccessMask.  Do you consider that claim to be incorrect?

Comment: @mjwach: Isn't that what your question was? Whether your interpretation was correct?

Comment: @krOoze: Execution dependencies alone will ensure "read->write" issues. Memory dependencies (which is what those are about) are exclusively about writing.

Comment: @nicolbolas Well this answers the question but suggests that Vulkan might after all need to be told about these "read->write" situations, and if it does then I need a little more explaining.  But you seem to be aligning with my answer on that point.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess. But how is the driver to know it is a "read->write" if you do not tell it. E.g. the from present handof with a layout transition. The question was why the flag even exists.

Comment: @krOoze: "*But how is the driver to know it is a "read->write" if you do not tell it.*" Why does it need to know? It's an *execution dependency*; by definition, the source stage(s) will have finished executing before the destination stage(s) start. The specification does not say that write-after-reads operations need this, while it does say that write-after-write and read-after-write operations do.

Comment: @NicolBolas You are forced to add memory barrier with a layout transition or queue family transfer.

Comment: @NicolBolas But I suppose you could provide 0 flag instead of READ. Except for presentation(they are quite explicit about `ACCESS_MEMORY_READ`). Maybe worth a GitHub issue. Actually I am getting serious deja-vu from this — there probably already is one...